# Elixir Logger customize metadata format

Tags: logging, elixir

In config.exs, I have `config :logger, :console, metadata: [:module, :function, :line]`

This will add `module=Module function=my_func/1 line=41` to the beginning of every debug message.

Instead, I would like to format the message in a more easily readable way for me: `Module.my_func/1(41)`.

Is it possible to segment out specific metadata in the config format specifier? It seems to me that I should be able to do something like `format: "$metadata[module].$metadata[function]($metadata[line])"` but this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but I think you have to use the [`:mfa` metadata option](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-metadata).

In your config:

```
config :logger, :console,
  level: :debug,
  metadata: [:mfa, :line],
  format: {MyLogFormatter, :format}
```

Then in your custom `MyLogFormatter` module, you would implement something like this:

```
def format(level, message, timestamp, metadata) do
    src =
      case Keyword.get(metadata, :mfa) do
        {m, f, a} -> "module=#{m} function=#{f}/#{a} line=#{Keyword.get(metadata, :line)}"
        _ -> nil
      end
    
    string = "#{src} #{message}"
    string <> "\n"
  end
```

You could add a clause or two if you wanted custom behavior depending on the level, but be careful when customizing this because it can really knee-cap your app if there's a problem.

If it works for you to adjust the log format using the formatting string, that is less work.